# seed object for reproducible results in parallel operation in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to use code for fully reproducible parallel models in caret but do not understand how to set the size of the vectors in the seed object.  For gbm I have 4 tuning parameters with a total of 11 different levels, and I have 54 rows in my tuning grid.  If I specify any value < 18 as the last value in the "for(i in 1:10)" line below, I get an error: "Bad seeds: the seed object should be a list of length 11 with 10 integer vectors of size 18 and the last list element having a single integer."  Why 18?  Also it runs without errors for values > 18 (e.g., 54) - why?  Many thanks for the help.  The following is based on http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html, added some things.

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
str(Sonar[, 1:10])
library(caret)
library(doParallel)

set.seed(998)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training <- Sonar[ inTraining,]
testing  <- Sonar[-inTraining,]

grid <- expand.grid(n.trees = seq(50,150,by=50), interaction.depth = seq(1,3,by=1),
  shrinkage = seq(.09,.11,by=.01),n.minobsinnode=seq(8,10,by=2)) 

# set seed to run fully reproducible model in parallel mode using caret          
set.seed(825)
seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = 11) # length is = (n_repeats*nresampling)+1
for(i in 1:10) seeds[[i]]<- sample.int(n=1000, 11) # ...the number of tuning parameter...
seeds[[11]]<-sample.int(1000, 1) # for the last model

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number = 10,seeds=seeds)               

# run model in parallel
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

gbmFit1 <- train(Class ~ ., data = training,method = "gbm",
  trControl = fitControl,tuneGrid=grid,verbose = FALSE)
gbmFit1
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error? I am however getting an error with your `train()` statement.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out.  It does run for me and gives the error.  I am using caret v. 6.0-47 which includes n.minobsinnode as a tuning parameter.

Comment: going to have to dig some but I'll keep looking. Which version of R are you using and what OS are you running?

Comment: I am using R version 3.1.3 and Windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 8):

I will address your question in two parts:

**1 - Setting the `seeds`:**

The code to do it as you stated :

```
set.seed(825)
seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = 11)
for(i in 1:10) seeds[[i]]<- sample.int(n=1000, 54)
#for the last model
seeds[[11]]<-sample.int(1000, 1)
```

The `11` in `seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = 11)` is `(n_repeats*nresampling)+1`, so in your case, you're using `10-fold CV`, so `10+1 = 11`. If you were using `repeatedcv` with `number=10 and repeats = 5` you would replace the `11` by `(5*10)+1 = 51`.

The `10` in `for(i in 1:10)` is `(n_repeats*nresampling)`. in your case it is `10` because you're using `10-fold CV`. Similarly, if you were using `repeatedcv` with `number=10 and repeats = 5` it would be `for(i in 1:50)`.

The `54` in `sample.int(n=1000, 54)` is the `number of tuning parameter combinations`. In your case, you have `4 parameters` with `3,3,3 and 2 values`. So, it is `3*3*3*2 = 54`. *But, I remember I red somewhere that for gbm, the model is fit to the `max(n.trees)` in the grid, and the models with less trees are derived from it, this explains why `caret` calculates the `seeds` based on the `interaction.depth * shrinkage * n.minobsinnode` in your case `3 * 3 * 2 = 18` and not `3*3*3*2 = 54` as we will see later.*

But if you were using a `SVM` model with a grid `svmGrid <- expand.grid(sigma= 2^c(-25, -20, -15,-10, -5, 0), C= 2^c(0:5))` your value is `6 * 6 = 36`

Remember, the goal of using `seeds` is to allow `reproducible research` by setting the seeds for the models fit at each resampling iteration.

The `seeds[[11]]<-sample.int(1000, 1)` is used to set the seed for the last (optimum) model fit to the complete dataset.

**2 - Why you get an error if you specify a value < 18, but no error with a value >= 18**

I was able to reproduce the same error on my machine:

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
  Bad seeds: the seed object should be a list of length 11 with 10 integer vectors of size 18 and the last list element having a single integer
```

So, by inspecting the `train.default` I was able to find its source. The error message is triggered by the `stop` in lines `7 to 10` based on the test `badSeed` in lines `4` and `5`.

```
    else {
        if (!(length(trControl$seeds) == 1 && is.na(trControl$seeds))) {
            numSeeds <- unlist(lapply(trControl$seeds, length))
4            badSeed <- (length(trControl$seeds) < length(trControl$index) + 
5              1) || (any(numSeeds[-length(numSeeds)] < nrow(trainInfo$loop)))
            if (badSeed) 
7             stop(paste("Bad seeds: the seed object should be a list of length", 
8               length(trControl$index) + 1, "with", length(trControl$index), 
9                   "integer vectors of size", nrow(trainInfo$loop), 
10               "and the last list element having a", "single integer"))
        }
    }
```

The number `18` is coming from `nrow(trainInfo$loop)`, so we need to find the value of `trainInfo$loop`. The object `trainInfo` is assigned a value `trainInfo <- models$loop(tuneGrid)` in line 3:

```
    if (trControl$method != "none") {
        if (is.function(models$loop) && nrow(tuneGrid) > 1) {
 3          trainInfo <- models$loop(tuneGrid)
            if (!all(c("loop", "submodels") %in% names(trainInfo))) 
                stop("The 'loop' function should produce a list with elements 'loop' and 'submodels'")
    }
```

Now, we need to find the object `models`. It is assigned the value of `models <- getModelInfo(method, regex = FALSE)[[1]]` in line 2:

```
    else {
2       models <- getModelInfo(method, regex = FALSE)[[1]]
        if (length(models) == 0) 
            stop(paste("Model", method, "is not in caret's built-in library"))
    }
```

Since we are using `method = "gbm"`, we can see the value of `getModelInfo("gbm", regex = FALSE)[[1]]$loop` and inspect the result below:

```
> getModelInfo("gbm", regex = FALSE)[[1]]$loop
function(grid) {     
3               loop <- ddply(grid, c("shrinkage", "interaction.depth", "n.minobsinnode"),
                              function(x) c(n.trees = max(x$n.trees)))
                submodels <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(loop))
                for(i in seq(along = loop$n.trees)) {
                  index <- which(grid$interaction.depth == loop$interaction.depth[i] & 
                                   grid$shrinkage == loop$shrinkage[i] &
                                   grid$n.minobsinnode == loop$n.minobsinnode[i])
                  trees <- grid[index, "n.trees"] 
                  submodels[[i]] <- data.frame(n.trees = trees[trees != loop$n.trees[i]])
                }    
                list(loop = loop, submodels = submodels)
}
>
```

The `loop` (in line 3 above) is assigned the value:

```
loop <- ddply(grid, c("shrinkage", "interaction.depth", "n.minobsinnode"),
                              function(x) c(n.trees = max(x$n.trees)))`
```

Now, let's pass your `grid` with `54 rows` to the line above and inspect the result:

```
> nrow(grid)
[1] 54
> 
> loop <- ddply(grid, c("shrinkage", "interaction.depth", "n.minobsinnode"),
+               function(x) c(n.trees = max(x$n.trees)))
> loop
   shrinkage interaction.depth n.minobsinnode n.trees
1       0.09                 1              8     150
2       0.09                 1             10     150
3       0.09                 2              8     150
4       0.09                 2             10     150
5       0.09                 3              8     150
6       0.09                 3             10     150
7       0.10                 1              8     150
8       0.10                 1             10     150
9       0.10                 2              8     150
10      0.10                 2             10     150
11      0.10                 3              8     150
12      0.10                 3             10     150
13      0.11                 1              8     150
14      0.11                 1             10     150
15      0.11                 2              8     150
16      0.11                 2             10     150
17      0.11                 3              8     150
18      0.11                 3             10     150
>
```

**ahh!, we found it**. The value `18` is coming from `nrow(trainInfo$loop)` which is coming from `getModelInfo("gbm", regex = FALSE)[[1]]$loop` shown above with just `18 rows`.

Now, going back to the test that triggered the error:

```
badSeed <- (length(trControl$seeds) < length(trControl$index) + 
              1) || (any(numSeeds[-length(numSeeds)] < nrow(trainInfo$loop)))
```

The first part of the test `(length(trControl$seeds) < length(trControl$index) + 1)` is `FALSE`, but the second part `(any(numSeeds[-length(numSeeds)] < nrow(trainInfo$loop)))` is `TRUE` for all valuse less that `18` [coming from `nrow(trainInfo$loop)`], and `FALSE` for all valuse greater than `18`. That's why the error is triggered for a value `<18` and not for `>=18`. As I said above, the caret's calculates the `seeds` based on the `interaction.depth * shrinkage * n.minobsinnode` in your case `3 * 3 * 2 = 18` (a model is fit to the `max(n.trees)` and the others are derived from it, so there is no need for `54` integers).

Comment: Brilliant!  Many thanks for chasing this down and providing a clear, detailed explanation.  I now understand that caret is using submodels in the case of n.trees for gbm.

Comment: is there an easier way to find what parameters are used for each model to determine the seed length?  I can follow GBM here but NNet is different...as are others